# How to iterate through unstructured txt file with list of invoices and its items and to create a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

guys
I have a txt file with a list of hundreds of invoices and its items, which varies from 1 to 10, depending on the invoice. The TXT file looks roughly like this one:

-------REPORT--------

Invoice..: 2000

Product BarCode Price

ASPIRIN

001001

5.00

Total: 5.00

Invoice..: 2001

Product BarCode Price

LOSARTAN

005001

5.00

VITAMIN

002111

10.00

Total: 15.00

Most invoices have only one item, and for this cases my code get all the data with the following code:

```
for idx, x in enumerate(lines):
    if 'Invoice..:' in x:
        invoice.append(re.search(r'(?<=Invoice..:).*', x).group(0))
    elif 'Product' in x:
        product.append(lines[idx+1])
        barcode.append(lines[idx+2])
        price.append(lines[idx+3])
```

I couldn't figure out how to correctly get product, barcode and price when there are two or more items in the invoice.

At the and, I want a dataframe like this:

| Invoice | Product | BarCode | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Aspirin | 001001 | 5.00 |
| 2001 | Losartan | 005001 | 5.00 |
| 2001 | Vitamin | 002111 | 10.00 |

Comment: Please provide the input text verbatim

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

# Function to read txt file in a list
def read_txt(path):
    with open(path, "r") as text_file:
        text = text_file.read().split('\n\n')
    return text
# Read txt file
lines = read_txt("file.txt")
# Create a list of index where Invoice..: is present
inv_lst = []
for i, x in enumerate(lines):
    if 'Invoice..:' in x:
        inv_lst.append(i)

# Create a dictionary of Invoice, Product, Barcode, Price
data= {'Invoice':[], 'Product':[], 'Barcode':[], 'Price':[]}
#loop through the list of index and split the list based on index
for i in inv_lst:
    inv_num = lines[i].split(' ')[1]
    invoice = lines[i:inv_lst[i+1] if i+1 < len(inv_lst) else len(lines)]
    #loop through the invoice list and fill the dictionary
    for item in invoice[2:]:
        if 'Total' not in item:
            if item.isupper(): #check if item is a product
                data['Invoice'].append(inv_num)
                data['Product'].append(item)
            elif item.isnumeric(): #check if item is a barcode
                barcode = item
                data['Barcode'].append(item)
            else : #otherwise item is a price
                data['Price'].append(item)
        

# Create a dataframe from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

> Invoice   Product Barcode  Price

> 0    2000   ASPIRIN  001001   5.00

> 1    2001  LOSARTAN  005001   5.00

> 2    2001   VITAMIN  002111  10.00

Comment: Thanks a lot, Parvez. My real case file is a lot longer than the example I've submitted, and I'm having problem with this line of your code:


` invoice = lines[i:inv_lst[i+1] if i+1 < len(inv_lst) else len(lines)] `


Your code access elements of list and I need to access them by the index. I know I have to use enumerate for this, but I don't know how to write it into a list comprehension.
Do you know how to insert the enumerate in this line of code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I managed a way to get the correct dataframe based on your code. Thanks a lot!